# TFS : Add options from expression

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, dotnet-cli

In TFS 2018, I use the task build "dotnet pack".
To generate a beta, I set the additional build properties to :

```
PackageVersion=2.0.$(Build.BuildNumber)-beta
```

To generate a release, I need remove "-beta" :

```
PackageVersion=2.0.$(Build.BuildNumber)
```

Is posible to add "-beta" from a expression? Like :

```
PackageVersion=2.0.$(Build.BuildNumber)$[ $(beta) ? "-beta" : "" ]
```

*$(beta) is a variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set the additional build properties :

```
PackageVersion=2.0.$(Build.BuildNumber)$(beta)
```

And the variable $(beta) has the default value "-beta".
For build a beta, I don't modify $(beta) variable. Then the package version is "2.0.145-beta".

For build a release, I remove the value in $(beta) variable. Then the package version is "2.0.146".

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not able to use this kind of expression `$[ $(beta) ? "-beta" : "" ]`.

As a workaround,  you could configure your release to unzip package, change the version and zip again.

- [Extract Files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/extract-files?view=azure-devops)
- [Archive Files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/archive-files?view=azure-devops)